# How to auto run one hundred C++ functions with same parameters?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ binary library.

There are almost one hundred C++ functions with different name, but same parameter types and same return type. And the values they parameter can be are equal.

I now want to test all of them with all of parameter values. And maybe return values to txt files.

How can I realize this? I want to store function names in a string list, and use eval() like python, but C++ doesn't have this feature.

Thank you!

Comment: "How can I realize this? I want to store function names in a string list, and use eval() like python, but c++ doesn't have this feature." That is definitely not how you should do this *in Python*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don' t know why not recommend use, this can save much of effort.

Comment: Because that is not a good use-case for eval and it is completely unnecessary. Instead, **just put the functions in a list**, there's no reason to use strings, you want *functions not strings*. Then just loop over the functions and call them.

Comment: Please show a [mre] for each language you want a solution in of how you currently test say three of the functions. Then answers can show how to change it to whatever solution they propose. (I think you only want C++ solution. Consider making that more obvious...)

Comment: @user202729 well, yes, it has all the downsides of dynamic code execution *and for zero benefit*.

Comment: Still, that API seems weird.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But, the function names have rules, so maybe I will write code to generate their names, not type one by one.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can create an array of function pointers and then loop over that array, calling each of the functions and giving always the same values to parameters from corresponding unchanging variables.

Comment: But, the function names have rules, so maybe I will write code to generate their names, not type one by one. Can I cast function names from std::string to std::function class? I don't know...

Comment: C++ is compiled. During runtome you cannot identify a function by its name. So you can generate function names for definition, i.e. for generating code to write their heads and bodies. But you cannot call a function by its name. Not without larger constructs like maps from name to pointer. And that in the end still be a container with pointers....

Comment: @zhonhel `std::function` can't help you here. There might be some slick tricks you can pull with preprocessor macros, but if you don't already know them or have time to figure one out, go with your idea of writing a program to generate the source code for the list of functions.